# Instalação template wrapbootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, temas

Comprei o template Genius Bootstrap e tive um problema em utilizar junto com o Rails.

Executei os seguintes passos:
Criei um app novo( rails new experimento) [ Rails 3.2.13]
Movi o conteúdo da pasta assets do template para vendor/assets
Mudei as referencias nas imagens, tanto no index.html.erb quanto no style.css

Adicionei a pasta fonts em vendor/assets/ 
Adicionei a linha: config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts") no application.rb
Renomeei o arquivo font-awesome.css para  font-awesome.css.scss.erb e mudei a declaração @font-face para o estilo:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    src: url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.eot')%>');
    src: url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix')%>') format('eot'), url('<%=    asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.woff')%>') format('woff'), url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.ttf')%>') format('truetype'), url('<%= asset_path('fontawesome-webfont.svg#FontAwesome')%>') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Contudo, parece que essa parte das fontes(e glyphicons) não renderiza(e deve ser a causa do sumiço do menu da esquerda e do footer). 
As imagens a seguir mostram como o site ficou e só faltou essa parte mesmo

http://imageshack.com/a/img801/9144/dn3t.png

http://imageshack.com/a/img841/4690/2pzk.png

Alguém aí experiência com instalação de temas bootstrap ou já utilizou este tema especificamente?

Já pesquisei bastante e contactei o criador do template, mas o mesmo não saca de Rails, logo, não tive sucesso =(

Comment: você está utilizando o asset-pipeline e incluiu o font-awesome.css.scss.erb no application.css?

Comment: Talles, tente ser mais específico quanto à sua pergunta, entendo que você explicou todo o processo, mas a dúvida final não está muito clara.

Answer (score 1):

Talles, seria interessante você verificar se no css compilado o path para as fontes está funcionando corretamente.

Implementei um tema do wrapbootstrap estes dias e utilizei o seguinte snippet para pegar a URL das fontes corretamente:

```
<%= font_path('fontawesome-webfont.eot')%>
```